# how to add conditional checkbox in listbox zk

Tags: java, javascript, frameworks, primefaces, zk

How to add conditional checkbox in listbox and this function should also work for select all functionality, we are displaying 25 items in checkbox should not be displayed for some items and when we select main checkbox then all checkbox should be selected.

For example, I have to list of image icons in listbox like image icon of PDF, jpg, gif, msword and excel etc. and the checkbox should appear only with PDF image icon and msword image icon, checkbox should not appear with other image icons. Also one checkbox shuld be in the header of listbox, the function of header checkbox like:- when we select the header checkbox then all checkboxes should be selected which appears with the PDF image icons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ZK forum Discussion for Conditional Checbox](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/80946/listbox-how-to-control-selectall-checkbox/)

According to this discussion you have to implement your own Checkbox in this case rather than using default checkbox of Listbox. This will easily resolve your issue.